Rollup says my const names are global, renames them with $1 suffix
I see this Q&A here, but that's for an obvious global named Promise.  I can find Promise in the MDN docs easily enough. But Rollup is renaming 4 of my consts that I don't find anywhere in any docs:

C
E
Is
CFunc

Are these really JavaScript globals? Where can I find docs for them? I don't want to rename them or wrap them in a namespace, but if there is a real conflict I'll have to deal with it.

The globals of JavaScript are listed in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

@jabaa - I don't find any of those 4 names on that page.  So what's up with Rollup?

Please ask one question per question. Your question was "Are these really JavaScript globals? Where can I find docs for them?" and the question was answered. If you have another question, create a new one. I wouldn't ask product specific questions on Stack Overflow. You could ask the devs https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues

"Rollup is renaming 4 of my consts" - so they are your constants. Why would you think that they would be JavaScript globals? Do you expect Rollup to deliberately cause the conflicts you are trying to avoid?

@Bergi - Rollup is adding a $1 suffix to these names that the rolled-up module exports. From what I can tell, that means that Rollup assumes the names to be previously declared as globals.  Is there another reason?  This module has no external dependencies - maybe I should have made that clearer.

"that means that Rollup assumes the names to be previously declared as globals" - no, not really.

@Bergi - OK, so it means there is another conflict.  But my module has no dependencies and these are used internally with no conflict.  What other reason is there?

@Bergi - I've created a new question focused on the Rollup part of this, if you wish to respond to these questions there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79239925/how-to-prevent-rollup-from-adding-1-suffix-to-names

@SidewaysS Maybe it renamed them to distinguish your own exports from the internal usages. Really we can't tell unless you post the code of your module (at least all the parts relevant to scoping, not necessarily function implementations) and the rollup options you are using.

@SidewaysS I don't think another question is necessary. This one is clear enough. Not sure why people are getting sidetracked on "Are these really JavaScript globals?"

@Bergi Please don't modify an answered question in a way that invalidates the answer. The original question asked for a list of JavaScript globals, not for any Roll Up fixes.

@jabaa The answer did not focus on the actual question, which is why rollup is renaming these variables (presumably because of naming conflicts with globals). The title should never have been edited.

@Bergi - for the first three names see src/globals.js in this repo: https://github.com/sidewayss/rAF.  There is a rollup.config.mjs file in the root directory.  As for the new question, yes the title here could change as my original assumptions were messy, but there is disagreement on this and I always defer to protocol-based requests here because wth do I know?

@Bergi Ok, than let's reroll the title to the orignal title. "The answer did not focus on the actual question" I don't see this question in the question. But I see "Are these really JavaScript globals? Where can I find docs for them?" I only moved the question from the description into the title.

@jabaa - the only edit I made was to add a line about no dependencies.  You all have been making the edits to the title.

@Bergi If that's not the OP's actual question, how difficult would it be to ask a new, correct question?

The only reference for global variables is the ECMAScript specification:
https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object
Please don't refer to anything else. Even MDN is confusing the spec with some specific implementation - like the HMTL specification.

Thanks for the info.  I can't find CFunc in that document.  I see only one reference to Is, and it's about a prefix, not a name.  E and C are hard to search for because they are used as Appendix headings and example variables.  So what is Rollup referencing here?

This is likely because you are using a variable name that is neither imported nor declared locally in the module. Or, that one of the package that you dépend one is doing so. Can you share the code sample where CFunc is used?

@SidewaysS Please ask only one question per question and don't ask follow-up questions in comments. That doesn't work well on this platform. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform and that doesn't work with multiple questions.

"The only reference for global variables is the ECMAScript specification" - this is wrong. That may be the ultimate reference for variables defined by the language, but what you really need to use is the documentation of the specific runtime the code will be executed in, as every runtime defines its own globals in addition to those of the language. So for a script to be executed in the browser, it is absolutely appropriate to check the HTML specification or MDN.

The question was "are these JavaScript globals ?" The answer is absolutely correct. Hopefully you are not the one that downvoted it'

@Bergi The question explicitly asks for JavaScript globals, not for globals of a specific runtime environment.

@jabaa That's the title you gave the question. It's not what the OP actually wants to know. This is answer is not helpful to them - even when it is technically correct.

@EricMORAND no external dependencies. see this repo: https://github.com/sidewayss/rAF.  For the first 3 names see src/globals.js.  There is a rollup.config.mjs in the root directory.

@Bergi The question was rolled back to the orignal state. The only two questions are "Are these really JavaScript globals? Where can I find docs for them?" My edit moved the questions from the description into the title. You see additional/other questions that I can't find.
