How to prevent Rollup from adding `$1` suffix to names?
I don't see how the answer to this question, @rollup/plugin-inject, solves my problem. So I'm asking a new question. Rollup is appending a $1 suffix to four names that my rolled-up module exports. My module has no external dependencies and I can't find any of the four names documented as already defined in the global scope

C
E
Is
CFunc

Why does Rollup consider these previously declared? Or is there another reason for this?
How do I prevent this? Or should I wrap these in a namespace? Anyone who imports them can wrap them or alias them.
This is a JavaScript library with named exports. The repo is here: https://github.com/sidewayss/rAF
See src/globals/js for the first three names. The fourth is declared in src/prop/func.js. See rollup.config.mjs for the Rollup configuration.
Also, see this previous question for various answers to a part of this question: Rollup says my const names are global, renames them with $1 suffix

Why is this a problem? Unless you are authoring a library which has actual named exports that other developers in other projects need to be able to import by their correct names, why do you care what rollup (or webpack, or vite, or...) names the stuff in your app? If you care deeply about the output of a compiler/bundler/other tool, well, this is Javascript: you always have the option of not using one!

It is a library that has named exports.  I should have made that clear in the question, and will do so now. Thanks for clarifying.

That's probably good context for your original question too FWIW. Next obvious thing: please post your rollup config and the relevant bits from your package.json (main, entry point, module, export map, etc.)

@JaredSmith - yea, I have really created a small nuisance here today, haven't I? It's just that it's difficult to even know the correct question sometimes, and there is a culture of such strictness here now, probably for good reason... I'll add that there too.  I also added a link back to that question here, Ugh. Thanks.

Yeah, there are good reasons for the strictness though. The biggest one is that it helps teach people how to break down a problem appropriately so they and/or someone helping them can find solutions more efficiently, not just for this problem but also the next 8,000 they are going to encounter. In your case it's doubly helpful: being able to get out of your own head and the context you already have is crucial for authoring a good library/API!

@JaredSmith - I added links to the repo and noted two relevant files. I had previously done that in the "original" question.  Thanks for your patience.

I figured this all the way out, and only because @rollup/plugin-replace doesn't replace all the $1 suffixes (it does replace some). This was caused by two things:

Circular import dependencies that Rollups warns about. I was paying no attention until I saw the warnings. I ended up being able to eliminate them all, with only one small inconvenience. After doing so I got back to this issue and saw that most of the $1 had been eliminated.
Undiscovered just-in-time compile bugs in obscure, untested functions, where the referenced name had not been imported. import {name} from "..."; solved that.

Now there is no more $1 in my bundled file, and I can uncomment my plugins and continue debugging.
